# Oracle SQL - How to Filter Out Duplicate Row Based on 1 Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I've Been trying to only get a unique value for 1 column. For Example I have a Table called "TBL"

```
COL_A   COL_B     COL_C
1        "HAT"     "RED"
2        "HAT"     "BLUE"
3        "SHIRT"   "BLUE"
3        "SHOES"   "GREEN"
```

I want to get the table to filter out all the duplicates for COL_A so the end result table would look like this - getting rid of 2 rows that have the duplicate 3 IDs. But still keeping all the columns just only filtering out the duplicates for one column.

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C
1        "HAT"   "RED"
2        "HAT"   "BLUE
```

I've tried multiple ways, first with the DISTINCT selector but after digging there still is a row left with the ID and I have also tried to use the GROUP BY selector and it also comes back with 1 row. If I can create a table that only has the unique values for COL_A then I can join that with my other table to only grab all the other columns but the table will only have the unique values for COL_A.

The statements I've tried were

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_A FROM TBL 
SELECT COL_A FROM TBL GROUP BY COL_A
```

I would think that one of these statements would be able to give me my result but instead it returns 3 even though the 3 id has 2 rows. If I could get it to return only 1 and 2 I can join that with another table to get all the other data for the unique IDs

```
COL_A
 1
 2
 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with A `IN` clause and a `Sub-SELECT`

> ```
> SELECT "COL_A", "COL_B", "COL_C" FROM tabl1
> WHERE "COL_B" IN (
> SELECT 
>  "COL_B"
> FROM tabl1
> GROUP BY "COL_B"
>  HAVING COUNT("COL_B") > 1 
>  AND COUNT(DISTINCT "COL_C") > 1)
>  ORDER BY "COL_A"
> ```
>
> ```
> COL_A | COL_B | COL_C
> ----: | :---- | :----
>     1 | HAT   | RED  
>     2 | HAT   | "BLUE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e6fd386219b5e00dc620ab5be8563dd)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` to find the ones that are not repeated. For example:

```
select *
from t
where col_a not in (
  select col_a from t group by col_a having count(*) > 1
)
```

Result:

```
 COL_A  COL_B  COL_C 
 ------ ------ ----- 
 1      HAT    RED   
 2      HAT    BLUE
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=70332b13d1309617ce69dd2a585eb455).

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause just generates the sample data and, as such, is not part of the answer.
You can get what you want using analytic function (Count() Over()) as in SQL below...

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "COL_A", 'HAT' "COL_B", 'RED' "COL_C" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "COL_A", 'HAT' "COL_B", 'BLUE' "COL_C" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "COL_A", 'SHIRT' "COL_B", 'BLUE' "COL_C" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "COL_A", 'SHOES' "COL_B", 'GREEN' "COL_C" From Dual 
        )
--  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C
FROM (  Select COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, Count(*) OVER(Partition By COL_A Order By COL_A) "ITERATIONS" From tbl  )
WHERE ITERATIONS = 1
```

More about analytic functions and how to use them at >> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 - this is the old one but good. Regards...